# What's the difference between include('file.php') and include 'file.php'

Tags: php, syntax

Both `include('file.php')` and `include 'file.php'` work and seem to be interchangeable.

Does anyone know if there is any difference between the two syntaxes? Performance? Introduced in a particular version?

I know if you're going to write `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/file.php';` it would probably look clearer to write `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/file.php');`

Comment: ["Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument. Take care when comparing return value."](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: I may be wrong, and forgive me if I am. But As a rule I also favour Require over include due to the fact it will inform you of more errors if something isn't correct.

Comment: @Blazemonger Not an issue, unless say you tried ` $result = include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/file.php');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. These are 'language constructs'. Syntactically this means that they can be used with or without braces. An example is `echo` statement.

`echo("hello");` and `echo "hello";` are the same

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference, because `include` is a language construct that doesn't require parentheses, just like `echo`.

See also: [include](http://sg.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-139) - scroll up a little bit

Answer (score 0):

include('file.php') ： calculate the value of ('file.php') firstly，of cause the value is file.php， and then include file.php into current file；
include 'file.php' ： include file.php into current file directly。
As you see， the result is the same， **but the second way is more  efficient。**

Comment: There's no difference in efficiency.